# javascript jquery find multiple hidden input without specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can javascript or jquery create an array of values from multiple hidden inputs with randomly created ids (in other words, no specific attribute to search for)? The code below only results in the alert of the first hidden input, 'abc'...
Thanks

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="abc" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="def" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="ghi" />

<script>
//create hidden fields array
var hiddenFields = [];

//for each table row
$('html').each(function()
{
  //get hidden field 
  if (hiddenField != $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val()){
  var hiddenField = $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val();
  }
  //if not empty push to array
  if(hiddenField!='undefined'&& hiddenField !=null )
    hiddenFields.push(hiddenField);
});
alert(hiddenFields);
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `each` on the html element?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID or you'll only return the first one. And where is your `body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only calling `.val` *once* after you `.find`, so it only returns the value of the first element in the jQuery collection. (`$('html').each` will only iterate once, because there's only one `html` tag in the document)

You can try something like this instead, no jQuery needed:

```js
const hiddenFields = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"]')]
  .map(input => input.value);
  
console.log(hiddenFields);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="abc" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="def" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="ghi" />
```

You should also try to fix the HTML so that there are no duplicated IDs; that's invalid.

If you wanted to use jQuery iteration:

```js
const hiddenFields = $.map($('input[type="hidden"]'), input => $(input).val());
console.log(hiddenFields);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="abc" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="def" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="ghi" />
```

Comment: Thanks 4 quick response and using both! Yea, was just trying to simplify the question visually..the id obviously shouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this:

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="abc" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="def" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="ghi" />
```

JS

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
  if(tags[i].getAttribute("hidden") == null){
    console.log(tags[i].value);
  }
}
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxRVMb?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Can use a combination of `filter()` and `map()`

```js
var results = $("input[type='hidden']").filter(function() {
  return this.value // only return elements that have value
}).map(function() {
  return this.value // pass the value to array
}).get()

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="abc" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="def" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="ghi" />
```

Comment: This worked too, thanks! I up-voted as well, but since I'm new user, will show up later when i have some activity.

Answer (score 0):

`Grab all hidden inputs and then you can fetch value by iterating on it using forEach loop`

```js
const hiddenInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"]');

const hiddenInputValues = [];

hiddenInputs.forEach((ele) => {
    hiddenInputValues.push(ele.value);
});

console.log(hiddenInputValues);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="abc" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="def" />
<input type="hidden" id="some_random_id" value="ghi" />
```